# How to set the Chrysler Grand Voyager Garage Remote

Tags: chrysler

How do I associate my garage door with the Chrysler T&C/Grand Voyager (same car)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that, as a first try, read the manual that came with the car.  It worked for me.  If that doesn't work, go back to the dealer.

Comment: Thanks, RTFM didn't work for me, ill try the dealer.